# WCF Service, WCF Service Application, ASP.NET, Observer Design Pattern

Tags: asp.net, wcf, web-services, service

I have an existing application (WPF) that monitors OPC Servers and alarms. There is a requirement for this to be accessible via a browser so that users can view the status of alarms etc remotely. I'm feeling out of my depth (I'm not a Web developer) and I just need some advice on the best technology to accomplish this.

I've written several WCF Services, but all these have done is, via a function call, crunch some data sending back a result.

This 'service' will have to be persistent and able to be interrogated by x number of clients. For example, a client will need to be able to connect, stay connected and be informed of events as an when they happen. This has been a major problem in the past when I've developed WCF services (channel faults etc) and I've learnt to only keep a connection open for as long as it's needed. Is a WCF Service the best option in this case (as opposed to a normal Window's Service)

I need to be able to 'push' information from the service to clients. So, someone navigates to a webpage, the page shows in realtime, what is happening in the service. Do I need to use timers since this could be big problem if session state cannot be maintained.

I've read about Observer Design Pattern, but can this be implemented in ASP.net and how would  ASP connect (and remain connected) to a remote windows service? Again, do I have to resort to timers?

I apologise it this appears vague, but the situation boils down to the following:

A process that's continually running (somewhere), receiving connections from remote clients (desktop/web), and then keeping the clients informed as events (alarms going off etc) occur.

Comment: This question is way too broad, but I don't see why a simple WCF service wouldn't solve the problem if you let the clients poll the service. If they need to be informed in realtime, then you can use a callback binding, but, as you say, at a cost. It also won't work unless the client is running .NET.

Comment: Thanks for this and Yes, the question is too broad. The main biggy is the Realtime issue. I've written WCF services before that needed to be called randomly, yet frequently and so tried to keep the connection open to avoid the expense incurred when opening. BUT. This is a whole world of pain with random channel exceptions (even when client and host are localhost machine). I wondered if there was an alternative way this could be achieved. Again, thanks for replying.